# Rigid Body play dice (Box) calculated from the bounding box to big

Tags: rigidbody

[image: left cube (play dice) rigid body to big]

Hey together 
**my problem:** 
The size of the play dice rigid body box is to big. 
I want it like the rigth cube to get a realistic animation later on.

**what i tried:**
shift + alt + ctrl + C to set Geometry to Origin .
put both cube´s on top of each other and click on the pivit point of the correct one with my cursor than switch to the play dice and set Geometry to 3D cursor. 
 Nothing worked. 
I am a newbie so i have no clue how to use code for solving. 
I read the manual [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties.html#rigid-body) and several forum entrys. But i don´t get to a solution.

[image]

For any Approach i would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box collider is calculated around all the vertices, even if they have no faces attached.

Go into edit mode and select the single stray vertex which is a little further from the surface of the cube. You can also select it with the *Select Non Manifold* command <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

Delete it and the rigid body box collider will encase the cube as expected.

[image: stray vertex]

Comment: Thx very much solved it :-) .